# Get Value from java script to viewData in layout

Tags: asp.net-core, westwind-globalization

ViewData value pass dynamically in mean language

ViewData["ame"] ="en-En";

@DbRes.T("Home","Menu",@ViewData["ame"])

Now Culture dynamically pass  en-En ,fr-Fr, using Java script

Comment: Hmmmmm... It is hard to understand what you are asking, I am afraid.

Comment: Did you mean you do not know how do use the `@ViewData["ame"]` in the js code which is in the Layout?

Comment: yes @viewData ["ama ] in Layout